# How to unstack data from one column to multiple column?

Tags: csv

I have a csv file which all the data in one column like

```
   A
8;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 16:51:58.753
9;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 17:21:11.416
10;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 17:41:09.771
11;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 18:01:22.448
```

and I want

```
A    B                  C            D         E            
8   a5747dfae47cccc8  7382625596    Anil    2017-08-07 16:51:58.753
9   a5747dfae47cccc8  7382625596    Anil    2017-08-07 17:21:11.416
10  a5747dfae47cccc8  7382625596    Anil    2017-08-07 17:41:09.771
11  a5747dfae47cccc8  7382625596    Anil    2017-08-07 18:01:22.448
```

Comment: In your question is there the input you have together the output you want? Could you add some sentence "this is my input, this is the output that I want"?

Comment: I have edited your question, now is simpler to understand your question

Comment: Did you find the right answer for you? If so, mark it below, otherwise leave a comment to the answers you've had and explain why they don't work

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you add "A;B;C;D;E" you have what you want: it's a five columns CSV with ";" as field separator

```
A;B;C;D;E
8;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 16:51:58.753
9;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 17:21:11.416
10;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 17:41:09.771
11;a5747dfae47cccc8;7382625596;Anil;2017-08-07 18:01:22.448
```

If you want to use the command line, you must delete first row (I use sed) and then pretty print your input (I use Miller https://github.com/johnkerl/miller)

With

```
<input.csv sed -e '1,1d' | mlr --n2p --ifs ";" then label A,B,C,D,E
```

you will have

```
A  B                C          D    E
8  a5747dfae47cccc8 7382625596 Anil 2017-08-07 16:51:58.753
9  a5747dfae47cccc8 7382625596 Anil 2017-08-07 17:21:11.416
10 a5747dfae47cccc8 7382625596 Anil 2017-08-07 17:41:09.771
11 a5747dfae47cccc8 7382625596 Anil 2017-08-07 18:01:22.448
```